# Can I use my iMac late 2015 non-retina display in Target Mode?

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, target-display

I'm trying to connect my Macbook Air (early 2015) to my iMac (late 2015 non-Retina display). I know that the 2015 Retina display iMac can't be used in Target Display Mode, but does that mean non-Retina display iMacs can't be either?

Answer (score 4):

Here are the iMacs that support Target Display Mode:

[image: iMac (27-inch, Late 2009); iMac (27-inch, Mid 2010); iMac (Mid 2011-Mid 2014)]

See more: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592